# No differences between some fonts in html

Tags: html, css, fonts

IMHO, the most popular sans-serif fonts in HTML are Arial and Helvetica. And I see absolutely no difference between these fonts. For exemple in this code

```
<!doctype html>
<html><body>
<p style="font-family:sans-serif">I'm seventeen.</p>
<p style="font-family:Arial">I'm seventeen.</p>
<p style="font-family:Helvetica">I'm seventeen.</p>
</body></html>
```

all three paragraphs are identical. It is ok?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about visually distinguishing fonts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differences between Arial and Helvetica are quite subtle, so you might not be able to tell the difference. [This website highlights some of the more obvious differences](http://ilovetypography.com/2007/10/06/arial-versus-helvetica/) such as the shape of the tail on a capital Q character.

Since they look very similar, some systems will substitute one for the other if both are not installed (in particular, Helvetica is likely to be rendered using Arial on Windows systems).

Comment: So it depends on computer?

Comment: they depend on operating system. Each operating sistem(iOS, windows, linux) has a generic font family. For example, sans-serif will fallback to a default operating system font value, while arial will be available on windowsonly (i might be wrong here, i'm not sure if he doesn't have support on other platforms too). Anyway, the visual difference is almost unnoticeable, since they are all font without serifs(sans-serif)

Comment: @lucianandrei arial comes installed on macs as well, but I think it just defaults to Helvetica

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are expecting to see here. Based on your HTML, I would expect those to be the same. Arial is a Windoze font, Helvetica is typical on Apple products - Sans-serif is the generic name for either.

The font used to render is selected by the browser from what is available on the user's computer.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser’s default meaning of `sans-serif` would probably be Arial. And, if you are using Windows, Helvetica maps to Arial. If you are using Mac, Helvetica is installed but they look extremely similar.

Answer (score -2):

Typically, fonts are declared like below (in order of preference) so that when one does not exist on the system, the next in the list is used.

```
<!doctype html>
<html><body>
<p style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">I'm seventeen.</p>
</body></html>
```